# Add field to active SFMC Data extension

Tags: data, extension, marketing-cloud, edit

Can you add additional fields to an active Data extension?  These data extensions are currently being used to populate Active Journeys so I was not sure if I could add additional fields to the DE.

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column on the property screen of the data extension in Subscribers. You cannot add a non-nullable column though.

You can do this in the UI or via [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/adding_new_column_to_an_existing_data_extension.htm)